# Filesharing mac 10.6 with windows vista

Tags: windows-vista, osx-snow-leopard, file-sharing

Ive followed all the tutorials on the net to no avail.

I can see my vista pc in finder on the mac but when I click on it tries to connect but fails. The same is true from vista, it can see the mac but i cant connect. Wont even offer a login box.

So I tried to troubleshoot by using a 3rd computer with xp. It joined the network and can access both the mac and vista on the same workgroup. Mac sees it and it shows under finder but i cant access it by clicking on the icon i have to access by using the ip of the xp machine...strange.

Ive turned off all my firewalls. The fact that xp can connnet to the others and vice versa boggles my mind why vista and mac cant connect directly.

Oh and pings indicates the same. I.e. xp has no problem but mac to vista and vice versa fails.

Can anyone help.

Comment: check for presence of 3rd party firewall and anti-virus software

Comment: Ive turned them all off, unless vista has an extra one runnng but I cant see any trace of one. Also if there was a firewall on vista, how am i connecting with the xp to it?